# DB.Null equivalent in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Is there an equivalent of (ADO.NET) DB.Null in JDBC? Or do I simply pass null in the parameter?

Particularly in the context of Mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [PreparedStatement.setNull()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). To set a parameter in a `PreparedStatement` object to null.